# Cannot load mod_ssl.so into server: ap_map_http_request_error

Tags: apache, ssl

Admittedly it's been a while since I've touched this server, but my cert expired and I needed to upload its replacement.

When attempting to restart Apache, now I'm getting:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 222 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: 
Syntax error on line 12 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf: 
Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so into server:
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: ap_map_http_request_error
```

The lines in question are simply:

```
# httpd.conf
Include conf.d/*.conf
```

And

```
# conf.d/ssl.conf
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588706/mod-ssl-fails-to-load-on-apache-restart-after-a2enmod-ssl-with-error-undefined-s) doesn't have an answer, and I'm not entirely sure it's a dupe because I'm not using `a2enmod`, and my `apachectl configtest` throws the same error as starting httpd does.
- [This thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/upgrading-apache-to-2-4-9-openssl-error-ssl_get_srp_userinfo-4175500874/) is about compiling from source; I'm not doing that, although I did upgrade SSL to patch the same vulnerability a while ago. Related?

As far as I can tell, nothing has changed in this config file, and I've verified that permissions are set properly for the new certificate files. What's going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that this was indeed caused by the upgrade to OpenSSL on my server. This isn't exactly an answer, but I worked around the problem by upgrading to Apache 2.4.

Word to the wise, that isn't an easy feat - read the docs first and back up your conf files.

Some tips along the way:

- Your conf files (should) be automatically backed up, and new sample files will be created. You'll need to go through your loaded modules one by one to disable/enable appropriate ones.
- [This](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1389642#p1389642) forum has a good tip about php5 and MPM (multi-processor Apache). If you're using a non-fpm version of php, use:

  ```
  LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
  ```
- You may run into conflicts with existing modules (e.g. `mod_ssl`) that got lost in the 2.4 upgrade. You'll need to manually remove *all* of those packages.